# Searching Strings containing a regex in createCriteria Method

Tags: java, regex, grails, groovy

I'm using Grails for my web app project. I know the createCriteria method can perform search on existing entries in database. Let's say I have a domain "some_domain" which includes a string variable "domain_string". I want to find out all "domain_strings" that contain either a 7-digit or 10-digit number starting with "1" or "7". (e.g. domain_string1 = ".........1234567.......", domain_string2 = ".......7192839265......", etc)

In my code:

```
some_domain.createCriteria().list() {
   rlike("domain_string", "%/^(1|7){7,10}/%")
}
```

I've used java regex here and the grails doc tells me that rlike is for regex input. But I can't get the exact output by the code because I'm not familiar with the groovy syntax. Any suggestions for that? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Quick reminder that rlike is only supported when using Oracle or MySQL.  You didn't specify so I'm guessing you're using one of those, but if not, this won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
rlike("domain_string", /([^0-9]|^)[17][0-9]{6}([0-9]{3})?([^0-9]|$)/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tiCz2f/2).

*Details*:

- `([^0-9]|^)` - either a non-digit char or start of string
- `[17]` - `1` or `7`
- `[0-9]{6}` - any six digits
- `([0-9]{3})?` - an optional occurrence of three digits
- `([^0-9]|$)` - either a non-digit char or end of string.

Comment: @NiC Another variation: `/(?<!\d)[17]\d{6}(\d{3})?(?!\d)/`

Answer (score 1):

Groovy regex by java native rules would look like:

```
def RE = /\D*[17]\d+\D*/

def domain_strings = [ ".........1234567.......", ".......7192839265......", ".......3192839265......", , ".......4192839265......" ]

domain_strings.each{
  boolean match = it ==~ RE
  println "$it matches? -> $match"
}
```

prints:

```
.........1234567....... matches? -> true
.......7192839265...... matches? -> true
.......3192839265...... matches? -> false
.......4192839265...... matches? -> false
```

You should check your DB SQL dialect if can consume such expressions as-is.